# Can't open shapefile with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, pycharm

I downloaded a shapefile from the Brazilian Institute of Geography and Statistics (IBGE). I can open it on QGIS and work with it perfectly there, but I need to work with it using Python.

I'm trying to open it with GeoPandas using the code line bellow:

```
shp_pr = gpd.read_file("data/PR/PR.shp")
```

But I get the following errors:

```
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
```

I've also tried with GDAL, using these code lines:

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
ds = driver.Open("data/PR/PR.shp", 0) #open your shapefile
```

But I get these errors:

```
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

I have all the ".cpg", ".dbf", ".prj", ".qpj", ".shp" and ".shx" files.

What is going wrong?

Comment: How did you install geopandas and its dependencies?

Comment: I used conda install -c conda-forge geopandas

Comment: Error message means that some support files which are needed by the proj library are not found. Did you set GDAL_DATA as adviced?

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do this?

Comment: Are you running this code from an activated conda environment or are you using an IDE and just pointing to the python interpreter in your conda environment?

Comment: I'm running it from pycharm using a python interpreter in a conda environment

Comment: Pycharm doesn't activate your conda env properly.  Workarounds: run pycharm by opening it using the command line from an activated conda env, or use [exec-wrappers](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/exec-wrappers), or set the required env variables in the pycharm run config for each script you want to run.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just set the environment variable as `PROJ_LIB` with value as `C:\Anaconda3\Library\share\proj`. This address contains `proj.db` file.